# ¿Como generas variables automáticamente para datos asignables?

Tags: python, tablas, frecuencia, estadística

Soy muy nuevo en programación y estoy intentado hacer un programa para hacer tablas de frecuencia pero no se como hacer un bucle que me permita generas variables para los datos a igresar.
Lo que intento es que en el bucle while te solicite que introduzca cada dato y se guarde en una variable diferente por cada ves. Estoy pidiendo que metan el numero de datos para que se repita el bucle la cantidad de veces necesarias para almacenar todos los datos de la tabla pero como digo no se como hacer que se generen nuevas variables para cada dato. Intente utilizando formulas como variable pero no funciona. Alguien consejo o idea para hacerlo?

```
numero_de_datos=int(input("introduca el numero de datos "))
i=1
while i<=numero_de_datos:
    dato1+1=float(input("introdusca valor ",i))

    i=i+1
```

Comment: Por favor edita y muestra lo que lleves, considera leer [ask]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solo basta con crear un array en el cual vas a ir almacenando los valores y para acceder a ellos lo puedes hacer por medio de subíndices, por ejemplo:

```
numero_de_datos = int(input("introduzca el numero de datos: "))

#Lista donde se almacenarán los datos.
datos = []

#Dandole valores a la lista vacía datos.
for i in range(numero_de_datos):
    datos.append(float(input("introduzca el valor{}: ".format(i+1))))
```

Posteriormente para obtener los datos de la lista, basta con usar subíndices:

```
for j in range(numero_de_datos):
    print(datos[j])
```